# Decrypting MSWord documents

Tags: c#, encryption, ms-word

I have a large subset of encrypted word documents which i need to process with out knowing the encryption password.

From looking around online, it seems that there are several services which strip the encryption from a file.  This is a perfect solution for my needs, but due to security/privacy reasons, i can't send the files to a 3rd party to be decrypted.

Can any one help me with any resources to point me in the right direction for removing encryption from office documents?

**Edit** For those with concerns on legality. While you have no reason to trust me, this question relates to working with conversion of legacy data into new systems, and is with in legal/moral bounds what the of the owner of the data wants done to it.

Comment: With a question of such debatable legitimacy, you might want to give the fine people who might contribute something to suggest you're not doing something illegal / immoral

Comment: Interesting. Due to security/privacy concerns, you're looking for a way to forcibly override security/privacy measures.

Comment: I work for a company that converts medical data from legacy systems to formats importable into their new hospital systems.  So while the hospitals hired us for the processing of their data, their IT departments are less then competent to provide us with all the required information on the storage of their data.

Comment: Also I am very disappointed that a valid question on programing is being down-voted here.  Further more the legality and morality of this problem have already been solved companies online that provide this service.  If what i was doing was illegal/immoral, I wouldn't much care about the privacy of the information with the documents.

Comment: Although I'm not one of those who downvoted, I suspect that people have downvoted based on the concerns expressed in the first comment. Had you included some background information in your question, I think you would have better luck. There *are* quite a few questions that get asked here of dubious legal/ethical merit, and I think it's desirable for the community to have some sensibility regarding those things. No one has voted to close this so far, so the concern is not that your question is off-topic. I actually don't think there's a simple way to do this without knowing the password.

Comment: @SergeiGolos: Expect to be downvoted any time your question or answer suggests something unethical; that way you won't be very disappointed.

Comment: @Will Honestly, I am not that disappointed about the downvotes.  While browsing stackoverflow with less ads is nice, my stackoverflow score isn't really that important to me.  What does disappoint me is that instead of coming here with any helpful information every one seems to think it is their duty to lecture me on the ethics of the situation.  What I am doing is for legitimate work reasons and does need to/will be done, the question is how much of a pain in the ass it will end up being.  My hope was that stack overflow would help.

Comment: @SergeiGolos: The thing is, people who answer questions on StackOverflow are doing so out of the kindness of their hearts.  They don't get much of anything for helping.  This means they tend to be more ethical than the average person, which means if something smells hinkey to them they are more likely to take a negative view of it.  While your motivations are known to you, they are opaque to everyone else due to the fact that the intertubes can't transmit them...

Comment: @Will: I totally understand what you are saying, but at the same time almost any question asked on here could be used for gray area work.  Some one asking for layout help might be working on a fishing page that resembles a bank login screen.  But we don't wrestle with ethics when helping some one with CSS.  Granted, breaking encryption is easer to label as gray area.

In any case, at this point i have basically given up on getting help here on this topic, but it would have been nice if some one at least pointed me to a doc file structure as a starting point for my work.

Comment: You've got to remember that while your cause might be sound, the answer here will be available to the world forever - a search for 'decrypting msword documents' and this'll be a central resource for bypassing security.

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone  The answer is already out there.  Adding another link to the internet doesn't change the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, i would like to say i am very disappointed with the response i got to my question.  Is my questions questionable in morality?  Yeah it might be, but i am not asking for anything that isn't already out on the web.

For anyone else who finds themselves in the same predicament, here are some good starting points:

- [BlackHat-EU-2010-Filiol-Office-Encryption-slides.pdf](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-eu-10/presentations/Filiol/BlackHat-EU-2010-Filiol-Office-Encryption-slides.pdf)
- [Office File Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118.aspx)

As for my work on this, the linked document doesn't produce a viable solution in my case.  We decided to shift our entry point to reading the heap for the specific application.

Answer (score 1):

> "*while the hospitals hired us for the processing of their data, their IT departments are less then competent to provide us with all the required information on the storage of their data.*"

If you've got HIPPA privacy concerns with data that keeps you from outsourcing the removal of document protection, you'll need to get past the security with the internal IT resources who, if competent enough to add protection, should be prepared to bypass it.

Comment: In an ideal world, the IT department would be competent enough to know what how their data is protected.  However, the data is protected with in the actual content management system we are trying to process for them and they don't have the slightest idea of how individual files with in the CMS are protected more over the actual pass phrase(s).

Comment: +1 on beth's comment. You're going to be much better off getting info from the CMS vendor about this than you will be trying to reverse engineer their encryption phrases. if the Vendor isn't forthcoming, go back to the hospital IT and have THEM discuss things with the vendor via support channels.